# Is it possible to get custom heads in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Before you say

> Oh, this is a duplicate of ***insert thread here***

I've already read some of them, they all say something about a component tag thats being added. Well while messing around with commands and typing "/give" the template says this

`/give (player: target) (itemName: Item) [amount: int] [data: int] [components: json]`

So since those questions were asked awhile go, did they add components, can we get custom heads now?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `compontents` tag, although it was added, is much more limited than real NBT. This is covered by the pre-existing canonical NBT question, which this is therefore a duplicate of.

Comment: If you already know the duplicate question and you already know the wiki page, why do you still ask?

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to obtain them using a command in vanilla minecraft, but I know that, with all the changes being made to behaviour and resource packs, it should theoretically be possible to add new heads into the game without replacing pre-existing mob heads with addons in the future, if not already.

Answer (score -2):

I think maybe you can make a texture pack and edit "head". It may cost money though, but idk how to get it free. If you do not want to pay any money, just search "block creator free" on your app store. If you are fine paying, I would recommend the one by seejaykay.